# Any examples of outstandingly well-made complete iOS apps with available source?

Tags: objective-c, ios, architecture, decoupling

I'd like to look over some really good iOS apps to see how they're put together. I've specified 'complete' because I'm more interested for current purposes in strategy than tactics (but hopefully the code will be tactically well-made too). 'Complete' needn't mean 'large'.

My own initial priorities would be that the overall design be cocoa-idiomatic (ie. make good use of what Apple have provided for us), with a heavy emphasis on classes being as decoupled as is possible within the relevant design constraints. But I'd be interested in any answers that give good reasons for specific openly-available code bases to be worthy of close examination.

Edit: Though my primary focus here is on apps, instructive examples of libraries could also be of interest.

Comment: @drewk: if that's a hint, could you be more specific? Or do you think there's nothing to be gained from reading over source that isn't in books?

Comment: Why was this question closed? The reason given looks like corporate boilerplate that's been pasted in, and doesn't seem to apply to what was asked.

Comment: The up-votes would certainly indicate some people see value in the question; not me personally - but that's just me.  Although - I agree that the scope of what you're asking is quite "all encompassing"; different apps will be "well made" for different reasons... are you after code quality? Performance? Extensibility? (etc)

Comment: @Adrian: well that doesn't necessarily mean anything (depends on who's doing the upvoting). Perhaps the question isn't of legitimate interest. But there's a tiny irony involved in closing a question on grounds of vagueness etc, and giving as a reason a pasted-in chunk of broad-brush boilerplate. It leaves me with no idea, for example, of whether I should be trying to ask the question in a better way, or just dropping it altogether.

Comment: I have to be honest that I think there is a bit of elitism on StackOverflow.  The goal of this site is not to prove that you're smarter than others, it's to HELP others.  Code mentoring is just as valuable as any book.  Fundamentals are what you get from books.  Source gives you real life implementations that are many times more valuable.  Reading code is just as good as reading a book.  If anything the closer should close all questions simply for asking for examples or how-tos.

Answer (score 0):

I have learn so much about this just looking at the sample apps that Apple provide with XCode.